# Sending AT or like commands to modern day cellphones

Tags: mobile-phone

I remember a friend showing me how to connect his Nokia 3110 to the serial port of his computer and making calls and sending SMS from the computer through the phone.

Do the modern day phones ( not the smartphones with OSes ) have similar capability - has anyone tried it?

For example - my Samsung SGH-T819 has a USB interface that I can connect to my computer, but I would like to make calls and send SMS using this phone connected to the computer.

Cannot modern day phones pull of what very old phones could do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Modern phones create a USB-serial or RFCOMM (Bluetooth) connection for sending AT commands. Some may need to be put into a certain mode for it to work though.

Comment: It's possible that my phone has a USB-serial converter inside to which I can issue commands. The manual that shipped with the retail box of course has no such info - any idea which forum(s) I can approach to ask this question?

Comment: @PoorLuzer: I've pulled up a manual for the SGH-T819, and it doesn't even mention anything about connecting via USB, only Bluetooth. This means that you'd have to use RFCOMM.

Comment: @Ignacio : The phone has an internal modem accessible over the USB Port. If I were able to dial out a friend's number using the phone using standard AT commands ( which the phone should support as a modem? ) will I be able to speak with him? Or will using the phone as a modem disable all its voice calling ability?

Comment: You would have to send the AT command that switches to voice mode before you could speak with him.

Comment: Would you happen to know a good reference to the AT command that is likely to be supported by a modern gsm modem? The PDF that I have says the above command is 'AT#VLS' and it still does not switch to voice mode.

Comment: Nope. I'd try to find something specific to the phone model though.